# Silverstripe duplicate database field causing error in save and publish

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using Silverstripe 3.0

I had created a field in the class Page(Page.php) as

"LinkTo" => "SiteTree"

which already exists in RedirectorPage

Even after removing the line of code and building the database, the field still exists in Page and Page_live which is giving me an error while publishing...no error while saving to draft...and the content gets saved...the success message is not displayed and
Firebug console: Response: There has been an error

Is the field not removed from these tables even after building the database?

Answer (score 4):

silverstripe doesn't remove any fields form the database tables when running dev/build, in order not to loose any data, so you'll have to remove them manually when they become obsolete.

if a whole class is removed, the corresponding table is renamed to `_obsolete_[tablename]`.

don't know why you're having an error while publishing (did you remove the field from your getCMSFields function too?), but for more insight you should try enabling dev mode, see http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/debugging